# iOS app doesn’t resize completely when switching from portrait to landscape

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

We are currently experiencing an issue with our iOS app (v.9.3.5, on iPad). The app allows an user to select a picture from the gallery to be displayed after.

**Steps to reproduce**
1. Phone is in portrait mode and the picture selection will be done using this mode:

- if selected photo is a **portrait** picture (width < height) then the app will show this photo in a portrait mode (**works OK, picture is displayed correctly**)
- if selected photo is a **landscape** picture (width > height) then the app will switch to landscape mode and display the photo in landscape. (**doesn't work fine as the picture is displayed within half of the app, i.e. the app is not resized to fit the phone screen**). This seems to work fine when the app is freshly installed/started but after a few tries it stops working and resizing the whole device's screen.

  2. When phone is in landscape mode and picture is either a portrait/landscape photo, app is resized correctly.

**Environment**

- ionic info:

> Cordova CLI: 6.3.1 Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1 Gulp local:
>   Local version 3.9.1 Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0 Ionic App Lib Version:
>   2.0.0-beta.20 ios-deploy version: Not installed ios-sim version: Not installed OS: Mac OS X El Capitan Node Version: v4.5.0 Xcode version:
>   Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014

- ionic plugin list:

> com.ozexpert.devicemeta 0.0.2 "DeviceMeta"
>   cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
>   cordova-plugin-camera 2.2.0 "Camera"
>   cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
>   cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
>   cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
>   cordova-plugin-email 1.1.1 "EmailComposer"
>   cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
>   cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
>   cordova-plugin-fullscreen 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-fullscreen"
>   cordova-plugin-image-picker 1.1.1 "ImagePicker"
>   cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
>   cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation"
>   cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
>   cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.4-dev "StatusBar"
>   cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
>   ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

- index.html "viewport":

  > < meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" >
- config.xml

  > < preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
- tested on iPad (iOS 9.3.5)

**Things tested so far**
I've tested almost anything on the web, including patches to *Statusbar* plugin and anything around the *viewport* meta.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

**StatusBar** plugin was causing this issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the "Statusbar plugin was causing the issue"? Did you just remove it or did you solve it in some other way?

Comment: hi @REJH After debugging the app we figured out that the plugin was causing some memory leaks and the app was eating to much RAM. so we updated/patched the existing plugin with another version. Hope this helps.